# Displaying a BarChart using mpandroidchart with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

Am trying to use Kotlin to display a simple bar chart using mpandroidchart library. Most of the examples I've been finding online are using java, so copy the code, paste in android studio to convert to Kotlin, then try to fix the errors were necessary.
But i just can't seem to fix the one appearing when using the BarEntry as shown in the image. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**BarEntry** only accept `Float` and `FloatArray`. You are passing `Int` instead of `Float`. Use `f` after each value like:

```
val barEntry = BarEntry(8f, 0f)
```

**Or** convert your value to `Float` using `toFloat()` provided by Kotlin like:

```
val barEntry = BarEntry(8f, 0.toFloat())
```

Comment: @RupinyEric, Have you got the solution?

Comment: I tried your solution and it solved that problem. Am actually using the example of @RajuTukadiya. Though there is another error when: `val data = BarData(labels, barDataSet)`. It says "Type mismatch. Required: IBarDataSet!, Found: kotlin.collections.ArrayList<String>"

Comment: Also don't down grade your library version. If this solve then accept the answer and for further problem create another question mentioning that problem in details. Hope you understand. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

[image]

step 1:

```
dependencies {

implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4' 
}
```

step 2:

```
repositories {

maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

step 3:

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setBarChart()
    }

    private fun setBarChart() {
        val entries = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
        entries.add(BarEntry(8f, 0))
        entries.add(BarEntry(2f, 1))
        entries.add(BarEntry(5f, 2))
        entries.add(BarEntry(20f, 3))
        entries.add(BarEntry(15f, 4))
        entries.add(BarEntry(19f, 5))

        val barDataSet = BarDataSet(entries, "Cells")

        val labels = ArrayList<String>()
        labels.add("18-Jan")
        labels.add("19-Jan")
        labels.add("20-Jan")
        labels.add("21-Jan")
        labels.add("22-Jan")
        labels.add("23-Jan")
        val data = BarData(labels, barDataSet)
        barChart.data = data // set the data and list of lables into chart

        barChart.setDescription("Set Bar Chart Description")  // set the description

        //barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
        barDataSet.color = resources.getColor(R.color.colorAccent)

        barChart.animateY(5000)
    }
}
```

step 4 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
    android:id="@+id/barChart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `val data = BarData(labels, barDataSet)` raises error.  `Type mismatch.
Required:
IBarDataSet!
Found:
kotlin.collections.ArrayList<String> /* = java.util.ArrayList<String> */`

Answer (score -1):

Unresolved reference: barChart and Variable expected

```
        private fun setBarChart() {
        val entries = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
        entries.add(BarEntry(8f, 0))
        entries.add(BarEntry(2f, 1))
        entries.add(BarEntry(5f, 2))
        entries.add(BarEntry(20f, 3))
        entries.add(BarEntry(15f, 4))
        entries.add(BarEntry(19f, 5))

        val barDataSet = BarDataSet(entries, "Cells")

        val labels = ArrayList<String>()
        labels.add("18-Jan")
        labels.add("19-Jan")
        labels.add("20-Jan")
        labels.add("21-Jan")
        labels.add("22-Jan")
        labels.add("23-Jan")
        val data = BarData(labels, barDataSet)
        barChart.data = data // set the data and list of lables into chart

        barChart.setDescription("Bar Chart")  // set the description

        //barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
        barDataSet.color = resources.getColor(R.color.colorAccent)

        barChart.animateY(5000)
    }
}
```